# The Nearly Perfect Shuffle

Tags: python, algorithm, shuffle

To nearly-perfectly shuffle a deck of n cards using offset k, perform the following steps:

- Remove k top cards from deck D, placing them on a new pile P, one at a time.
- Split the remaining n-k cards equally into the top half (T) and the bottom half (B).
- Place the bottom cards of B and T on top of P in this order.
- Repeat the previous step until all cards are on P, which becomes the shuffled deck.

For example:
n = 11, k = 3 with starting deck from the bottom: 3 7 9 A 2 8 J K 6 4 Q
First we place Q, then 4, then 6 on pile P.
Then we split the remaining cards into bottom half: 3 7 9 A and top half: 2 8 J K.
The bottom card of B is then 3 which we place on P followed by the bottom card of T which is 2
Repeating the previous step, we end up with the shuffled deck: Q 4 6 3 2 7 8 9 J A K.
Your task is to write a program which, for given values n and k, outputs how many nearly-perfect shuffles are needed to return a perfectly sorted deck back to its original state.

Example Input 1

```
6  
0
```

Example Output 1
`4`
Example Input 2

```
11  
3
```

Example Output 2
`10`

Constraints

- 3 <= n <= 1,000,000
- 0 <= k <= n
- n - k will always be even for provided inputs
- The required outputs will not exceed 1018

I have puzzled for ages on this problem but I keep running into problems!
How am I supposed to solve this?

My code in progress:

```py
def shuffle(n, k):
  global shuffledA, shuffledB, shuffledZ, cards
  if 0 <= k <= n <= 1000000 and (n-k) % 2 == 0:
    cards = []
    shuffled = [None]
    shuffledA = []
    shuffledB = []
    shuffledZ = []
    num = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
      cards.append(i)
    shuffledZ = cards[n-1-k:n-1]
    shuffledA = cards[0:(n-k)/2-1]
    shuffledB = cards[(n-k)/2:n-k-2]
```

it always outputs this error when I run it where n - k is even:

```py
>>> shuffle(11, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 256, in shuffle
    shuffledA = cards[0:(n-k)/2-1]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: You have added the `python` tag, but you have added no code to your question.

Comment: I added my code in progress and my error message but Because of the error I haven't really got the foundations of the loop yet

Comment: I think you meant to write: `(n-k)//2` in both cases. `n/2` returns a `float`.

Comment: Oh yes that's true

Comment: I managed to produce working code for this Perse Coding Challenge question, but I only got up to 5/10 test cases correct, because for the other 5 test cases I would run into time out errors. Would posting my code answer your question?

Comment: I guess! It will be helpful thanks @Hari5000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of answering this question - **the second is more efficient** as it's faster, and this is why it scores full marks for the Perse Coding Challenge.

### The first (less efficient) way

is to create a virtual deck,  then virtually shuffle it. This works, but with larger values of n (e.g. 1,000,000) this can be slow, hence leading to a timeout when submitting it as an answer. My code is as follows:

```
#Accept inputs
n = int(input())
k = int(input())
it = 1

#Apply the Nearly Perfect Shuffle
def shuffle(string):
        P = []
        global n,k
        
    if k!=0:
    #Remove the bottom k cards, place them on top
    #last goes to first, second last --> second, nth last --> nth
        for i in range(k):
            P.append(string[-i-1])
            i += 1
        string = string[:-k]

    #Now for the "perfect" part of the nearly perfect shuffle
        
    #Split deck into two
    l = len(string)//2

    B = string[:l]
    T = string[l:]
    #Add the top card from each pile onto P one by one
    for i in range(l):
        P.append(B[i])
        P.append(T[i])
    return P

#Create a deck of cards
#We do this by creating an array containing numbers from 1 to n
first = list(range(n))
#print(first)
P = shuffle(first)

#We repeatedly shuffle until we get back to where we started
while P != first:
    P = shuffle(P)
    it += 1
print(it)
```

### The more efficient, less time-consuming way

is to find the mathematical pattern that lies behind each card shuffle.

- For every shuffle, the last card always becomes the first card, the second last always becomes the second... the nth last always becomes the nth.
- The rest of the deck is split into two.

  - Let's pretend k = 0 for simplicity, and the deck is: A B C D E F G H
  - A is in position 0, B is in position 1, etc.
  - Splitting it into two gives A,B,C,D and E,F,G,H
  - Perfect shuffle gives A E B F C G D H
  - Take notice of the positions of A, B, C, D. Before, they were in *positions* 0, 1, 2 and 3 of the deck respectively. Now, they are in positions 0, 2, 4, 6. All you've done is multiply their position in the deck by two.
  - Now lets look at E, F, G, H. They were in positions 4, 5, 6, 7 respectively but now they're in positions 1, 3, 5, 7.

    1. First we subtract the size of the first half of the deck from each position (e.g. 4-4 = 0)
    2. Then we multiply this by two like we did before (0*2=0)
    3. Finally we add (0+1=1) since the card has to come after the previous card, not replace it. E was in position 4, but now it's in position 1
- What you might notice when you follow the path of a single element in the array (a single card in the deck) is that it may loop through the same positions, e.g. a card that is found at position 2, then 4, then 5, then 0, then back to 2.
- Each card has their own "loop" sequence. Imagine a deck where card X at position 1 goes to 2, then 3 then 1 again, and card Y at position 4 goes to 5,6,7, then 4 again. After 3 cycles, card A returns to its starting point. After 4 cycles, card Y returns to its starting point. Therefore, for *both* cards to return to their starting point at the same time, we need 12 shuffles. This is because 12 is the lowest common multiple of 3 and 4.
- Essentially, you will need to find the lowest common multiple of the length of all the "loops" of all cards.

The code can be found [here](https://replit.com/@pdbaker/PCTC20-R2-Q12), but I've copied and pasted it below anyway.

```
"""
12) NEARLY PERFECT SHUFFLE - ALL MARKS
"""

from math import gcd
from functools import reduce

n, k = int(input()), int(input())
sizeHalf = (n - k) // 2

nums = set(range(n))
cycles = []

# example shuffle mapping
# n = 11 k = 3
# 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
# AFTER ONE SHUFFLE GOES TO....
# 10 9  8  0  4  1  5  2  6  3  7

def findCycle(i):
  # a different way of thinking 
  # ... can I track the card at index i as it moves around until it gets back to index i?
  #... how many moves does it take (its cycle length)?

  x = i
  count = 0 

  while True:
    
    count += 1

    if x >= n - k:
      x = n - x - 1
    elif x < sizeHalf:
      x = k + x * 2
    else:
      x = k + 1 + (x - sizeHalf) * 2

    if x == i:
      return count

    nums.remove(x)


while len(nums) > 0:
    cycles.append(findCycle(nums.pop()))

lcm = cycles[0]
for i in range(1, len(cycles)):
  lcm = (lcm * cycles[i]) // gcd(lcm, cycles[i])

print(lcm)

# or do 
# print(reduce(lambda a,b : a * b // gcd(a, b), cycles))
```